# How do I use printf to print some values and strings in a table format

Tags: c, printf

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

X+Y     X - Y   X/Y     X*Y

a         b      c       d

I have searched google and I didn't find exactly what I was looking for, tried multiple methods,it still shows messed up.

This is my code so far:

```
int main()
{
    int x,y,a,b,c,d;
    printf("Introdu X si Y");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

    a=x+y;
    b=x*y;
    c=x-y;
    d=x/y;
    printf("X+Y\t","X*Y\t","X-Y\t","X/y\t");
    printf("3%d,3%d,3%d,3%d",a,b,c,d);


    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:Removing the commas worked fine,and the 3's in the code, I thought you could allign to the left with 3 spaces using 3%d.Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Remove commas from the first printf(). Secondly the format of the second printf() should be only "%d". Why print 3 before each number?

Comment: Also you probably want newlines at the end. Add "\n" add the end of each format string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no need for the commas of the first print().

Secondly, the format you used in the second printf() is "3%d". It means that the number 3 will be printed before any number, and this is unnecessary.

Look at this code as an option to fix your problem (added some alignments and newlines)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x,y,a,b,c,d;
    printf("Introdu X si Y \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

    a=x+y;
    b=x*y;
    c=x-y;
    d=x/y;

    printf("X+Y\t X*Y\t X-Y\t X/y\t\n");
    printf("%d\t,%d\t,%d\t,%d\t",a,b,c,d);

    return 0;
}
```

Some possible output is:

```
Introdu X si Y 
6 3
X+Y      X*Y     X-Y     X/y
9       ,18     ,3      ,2
```

Note that the use of int variable for the division will always give you the result as integer. Hence, in your code: 1/2 = 0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your printf statements.

```
printf("X+Y X*Y X-Y X/y\n");
printf("%d %d %d %d", a, b, c, d);
```

I think you just want this.